# Single phase Ac Wire voltages

Tags: voltage, ac

I'm sorry for asking a question this simple but I can't understand it .
Single phase ac has two wires , phase and neutral but I don't know which wire change voltage . Like neutral wire is always 0 v and phase wire changing +V to -V or phase and neutral changes direction ? (Like phase +V , neutral 0V then neutral +V , phase 0V ).
Also what's the difference between pulse signal and ac ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neutral wire is connected to an Earth Ground somewhere, and is therefore defined to be "Zero Volts".  The voltage on the phase (or "live"  or "line") wire varies/alternates between positive and negative relative to the Neutral wire.

AC normally implies a regular alternating voltage (50 or 60Hz for Mains Power, but any frequency for other uses).

A pulse signal is normally at one voltage (often, but not necessarily, zero), but occasionally changes to another voltage for a short time.

Comment: So in ac , live wire changing between +V to -V ... And neutral is always ground (0v)? Also if you make a pulse signal which has +V (high ) and -V (low) , is it counts as ac or pulse ?

Comment: I still can't understand the difference , like if you make live +V and neutral ground then live is ground and neutral is +V . It's seems like same results for me.

Comment: @Mordecai:  Many times, technical terms don't have hard-and-fast definitions - the particular definition to use may depend on context.  If you are interested in the positive and negative voltages of a pulse signal, you may want to call it "AC", but if the pulse has random timing, or is mostly negative with brief positive periods, I don't think I'd call it AC.

Comment: For AC power, Neutral is always Ground/Zero volts (or very close to it), and the "Hot" wire varies regularly between a peak positive voltage and a peak negative voltage.

Comment: Okay now I think I understand it and I made simple test to check , I connected one probe of my multimeter to ground pin and other probe to live and it shown 220v but when I connect the other probe to neutral it shown 0V . So if these accurate , you can only get electrocuted with live wire ?